# Ethics of Spinoza - est ut

Tags: translation-explanation, ut

Spinoza, Ethics, De Deo, Propositio 33, Scholium 2:

> Quare **non est ut** in hoc absurdo refutando tempus consumam.

William White translates it:

> Therefore **it is not worthwhile that** I should waste time in refuting this absurdity.

Oxford Latin Dictionary:

> ***est ut***, It is the case that

I have found no dictionary or grammar book which writes **est ut** means **it is necessary**, **needed** or **worthwhile**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Est, ut* can indeed mean something like “there is reason to,” and conversely, when negated, something like “it is unnecessary.”

This applies to **non est, ut** (+ subjunctive) and similar forms like: **non est, quod** (+ indicative or subjunctive) / **nihil est, quod** / **nihil est, cur** etc. All these mean “there is no reason, it is unnecessary, not worthwhile.”

I cannot comment on the Oxford Latin Dictionary, but [Lewis & Short give (I.B.5.b.α)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsum1):

> Also, est ut, *there is reason, that*

(Note: Perseus completely messes up the structure of that article. It is much better displayed at [Collatinus-web](https://outils.biblissima.fr/en/collatinus-web/index.php), but I do not know how to link articles there, so you have to look it up yourself.)

One example they give is indeed negated (translation from the Latin, however, by me):

> neque est ut putemus ignorari ea ab animalibus
> *there is no reason for us to believe*, perhaps even: *we should/must not believe*

If you can read German, [Georges (I.B.d)](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/sum+%5B1%5D) (also available at Collatinus-web) is even clearer and mentions the negated case quite explicitly (translation from the Latin, where given, by Georges, and from the German by me):

> *however,* non est quod *or* ut *etc., or* nihil est quod *or* cur, *there is no grounds, I (you etc.) have no reason to etc.,* nihil est, quod gestias, Cic.: non est igitur, ut mirandum sit, *so one need not wonder,* Cic.

Comment: Thanks, specially for Collatinus-web.